# Detecting Href Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to detect if certain element is clicked on onbeforeunload. I can't get it to work. Below is examples of the Javascript code and HTML code on the project (Please note that I have no control over the HTML element as it is not my site)

```
function checkLeave() {
   var p = document.getElementByElementById('yeah');
   if (p.href.onclick) {
      //do something
   }

   else {
      //do something else
   }
   }
 window.onbeforeunload = checkLeave;


 HTML CODE
 //The goSomewhere goes to another page
 <a id="yeah" href="javascript:goSomewhere();">
    <img src="smiley.png">
 </a>
```

Thanks in advance,
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is bind an event handler to each `<a href=""></a>` on the page.
This can be done with the following:

```
// Select all links
//var allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');
var allLinks = document.links;

// Bind the event handler to each link individually
for (var i = 0, n = allLinks.length; i < n; i++) {
    //allLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {});
    allLinks[i].onclick = function () {
        // Do something            
    };
}
```

Comment: No need for qSA, in every browser in use there is a [document.links](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919) collection that is all the links in the document. Also, *addEventListener* is not supported by IE < 9 at least.

Comment: how to i pass the `a` link to itself in `onclick` function?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for the presence of the `onclick` property to the `<a>` tag.  It isn't present in the markup.  Rather than using the `onclick`, the markup calls a script as the element's href. So you need to look for a script in the href instead:

```
var p = document.getElementByElementById('yeah');
if (p.href.indexOf("javascript") === 0) {
   //do something
}
else {
   // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? (just the idea)

```
document.getElementById('yeah').onclick = function() {
  clicked = this.href;
};
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, i'm looking at the site and there seems to be some elements with no ID.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? that would simplify it a lot ^.^ -- Even better combine this method with greenfir3's